# Wordpress single-custom_post_type template not showing

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I created an custom post type, and the single-custom_post_type showing the index page not the post type page..

I don't understand why it showing the index page..

I refreshed permalinks,i used: `flush_rewrite_rules();`, but does not work

sigle-tv.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        test
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<!-- series -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

register post type

```
function tvshows_taxonomy() {
register_taxonomy('tv_categories', array('tv,episodes',),
array(
    'show_admin_column' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => true, 
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => get_option('tv-category')),)
);
}
add_action('init', 'tvshows_taxonomy', 0);
function prefijo_series() {
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'prefijo_series' );
// Register Series
function series() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'TV Shows', 'Post Type General Name', 'theme_name' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'TV Show', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'theme_name' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'TV Shows', 'theme_name' ),
        'name_admin_bar'      => __( 'TV Shows', 'theme_name' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => 'tv',
        'with_front'          => true,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'TV Show', 'theme_name' ),
        'description'         => __( 'TV series manage', 'theme_name' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail','comments' ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'tv_categories' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-welcome-view-site',
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'tv', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'series', 0 );
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Smith,

Your code is right nothing to change in it.
Just go to backend admin section and click on Settings -> Permalinks
After that select "Post Name" in radio buttons and click on Save Changes. Done.

Refresh your single page it will work.

Comment: This is definitely a good way to manually flush the rewrite rules but `flush_rewrite_rules()` should have worked to do this if it was actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say your call to `flush_rewrite_rules()` did not actually run. To be sure, add a quick manual flush to e.g. `functions.php`:

```
/* Trigger on wp-admin or cron and whathaveyou */
add_action('admin_init', function() {
   flush_rewrite_rules();
});
```

Flushing on init on a live site will degrade performance, etc. But it's useful to sanity check your flushes.

Comment: Then your actual problem does not seem to be contained in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, i included the register post type only for admin. THis was the problem